# Is mysql_fetch_array a the combination of mysql_fetch_assoc and mysql_fetch_row?

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

I have been reading about mysql_fetch_* methods. 
This is what I have learnt from PHP.org website.

```
mysql_fetch_array — Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both
mysql_fetch_assoc — Fetch a result row as an associative array
mysql_fetch_object — Fetch a result row as an object
mysql_fetch_row — Get a result row as an enumerated array
```

It looks like mysql_fetch_array contains all the values that are present in

`mysql_fetch_assoc,mysql_fetch_object,mysql_fetch_row`. Because `mysql_fetch_assoc` contains only Associative array,

`mysql_fetch_row` contains data in Numeric Array.

`mysql_fetch_object` also returns associative array.

Kindly tell me whether my understanding is correct or wrong.

Comment: You are correct except for the mysql_fetch_object part. mysql_fetch_object returns an object with column names being the properties of that object. This type of thing is not available from mysql_fetch_array

Comment: Yes, you're basically on the right track with that. However, please note that all the `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated and not recommended for use; if you're learning PHP, you should be learning a more modern API such as PDO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_assoc` returns an associative array, `mysql_fetch_row` returns a numeric array, and with `mysql_fetch_array` you can chose what would be the output. This function accepts an optional parameter which can take values:

- MYSQL_ASSOC - returns associative array
- MYSQL_NUM - returns numeric array
- MYSQL_BOTH - returns combined numeric and associative array

The last value is default.

`mysql_fetch_object` is slightly different as it returns an object wich has fields corresponding to columns in result fetched from database.

As a sidenote I would like to add that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and you should switch to `mysqli` or PDO.